# How to run Console Application Exe on SUSE (Linux)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linux, suse

I have developed a Console based program C# on windows server. Now I need to run on SUSE Linux Enterprise SP 13. I tried to install mono, but it doesn't download. 
Kindly please give suggestion how to run on Hana database install on SUSE Linux.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I wouldn't recommend you write any C# applications using mono. I would suggest you convert your application to leverage .NET Core which is supported in SLES. Converting your application should be straight forward.

.NET Core installation on SLES: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/sles12/sdk-2.1.802

I would also recommend 2.1 since it is the current LTS until 3.1 is released.

If you don't want to install .NET Core runtime, then you can easily create a self-contained deployment that doesn't require you to install anything on your system. The package is much larger to deploy, but you are not required to have the runtime installed on the system.

Here are the docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment